# Runtime Exception while launching xuggle application through JWS

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start, xuggle, xuggler

I get the following exception when i launch my application through JWS.But it works completely fine when launched as a standalone java application without JNLP.

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at com.xuggle.ferry.JNIMemoryManager.<init>(JNIMemoryManager.java:861)
at com.xuggle.ferry.JNIMemoryManager.<clinit>(JNIMemoryManager.java:860)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.<clinit>(MediaWriter.java:119)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeWriter(ToolFactory.java:149)
```

here is the JNLP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost/MyApp" href="MyAppLauncher.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>MyAPP</title>
    <vendor>Me</vendor>
</information>
<resources>
    <!-- Application Resources -->
    <j2se version="1.6+"
          href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="MyAppJar.jar"
        main="true" />
    <jar href="xuggle-xuggler.jar" />
    <jar href="xuggle-xuggler-test.jar" />
    <jar href="slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar" />


</resources>
<application-desc
     name="MyApplication"
     main-class=
       "ApplicationMain"
     width="300"
     height="300">
 </application-desc>
<security>
 <all-permissions/>
</security>
<offline-allowed />
 <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

MyApp.jar contains the main class file.All the JARS used are signed.

Comment: I updated the JNLP file org.slf4j.LoggerFactory is in slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar.

Comment: The error got rectified there was a problem with the Class-path mentioned in the manifest file of MyJar.Jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the Jar that contains `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` is referenced in the resources.
2. The JNLP is invalid. Be sure to check (& correct) it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).